# Open/close a browser window shortcut

Tags: shortcuts

I am trying to customize my Ubuntu 18 installation and having a struggle with keyboard shortcuts. Currently, if I want to open or close a browser window I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> respectively. I would like it to change to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, but couldn't find those shortcuts in the keyboard settings.

Is it possible to change them?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: @Kulfy, I use Google Chrome